# Why does mysql not taking amharic characters?

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSql. I want to use amharic language in my database. but the database is putting all the characters just like this (áŠ áˆ›áˆ¨áŠ› áˆ™áŠ¨áˆ) which is supposed to be like this (አማረኛ ሙከራ)  so please help me

Comment: Please share more details. Are these characters part of UTF8 or UTF16? If yes, share a sample table structure and a sample query to trigger that problem

Comment: i do not know what part are they but the sample code is



CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `newsid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `News` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `newsimage` blob NOT NULL
)

Comment: Well, `latin1` does probably not contain any characters which are not common in latin alphabets. I'm not sure where amharic is spoken, but the characters you've posted look pretty different to the ones we use in Germany. Please try to switch to UTF8 instead

Comment: thanks for your comment my friend  Nico Amharic is spoken in Ethiopia and i tried making it UTF8 but didn't work

Comment: Please add all attempts to the question by editing it - also, show that your whole application is UTF8 ready, including the connection to the database itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow any language to work on mysql change the collation of the database to utf8_general_ci

```
 ALTER DATABASE <dbname> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

and in order to view your data with any language from mysql database use the following code on your connection string

```
  <?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
mysqli_set_charset($link , 'utf8');
    ?>
```